# Cannot find my VF Page to override

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have created a visual page named "Account_display" but i Cannot find my VF Page to override in the list of pages.

can you please help me

Comment: Have you used the standard Account controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're missing `standardController` tag on your Visualforce page. Because for overriding any button of custom object you need Visualforce Page defined using **Standard Controller**. Refer below example:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account_display__c">
  <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
  <h1>Congratulations</h1>
  This is your new Page
  <!-- End Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
</apex:page>
```

Also if you want to display **List** of records for that particular object then use `recordSetVar` tag. Sample example would be:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account_display__c" recordSetVar = "records">
  <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
  <apex:repeat value = "{!records}" var = "record">
      <apex:outputField value = "{!record.Name}"/>
  </apex:repeat>

  <!-- End Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Chrome plugin to search that Visualforce page: 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-advanced-code/lnkgcmpjkkkeffambkllliefdpjdklmi

If is not there is probably been deleted.