# Overriding Same Visualforce Page for both new ,edit views

Tags: list-view

Is there any way to get which view(New or Edit ) iam using through apex.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: you can refer this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/164469/cannot-find-my-vf-page-to-override/164470#164470)

Comment: @Rohit I didnot ask how to ovveride the view..

Comment: It doesn't matter, you can override any button by defining a page with standard controller for that object.

Answer (score 3):

One way is that for the new case, the platform does not supply an `id` parameter and for the edit case it does so in Apex:

```
Boolean isEdit = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id') != null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can know it by getting the id parameter. If the id is null then it is a new page, else its a edit page.
Like this: ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')